# AngularJS retrieving user object from controller on every request

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have successfully setup a Spring Security project which authenticates the user whenever he logs in. However, after he logs in, I want to retrieve this user object (which is inside the session of Spring security) via the Rest controller in every controller function of AngularJS.

To clarify, how can I call the following method each in every controller to retrieve the user object?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getLoggedInUser", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public User getLoggedInUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
                    .getPrincipal();
            return user;
        }
        return null;
}
```

What I did was the following:

```
$http.get(urlBase+'/getLoggedInUser').
 success(function(data) {
     $scope.users = data;
     console.log("The logged in user is: " + data.firstname);
})
```

This works and it prints the firstname, but I get some odd behaviour when I put the above method inside another $http get method. Is there a better option or possiblity of adding this function at the beginning of every angularjs controller to retrieve this user object and check whether it is null or set (so I can do some logic with it)?

***********UPDATE***********
After the suggestion of pankajparkar, I was able to now simply retrieve the user object. I put the get method in the application factory directly as such:

```
myApp.factory('accountService', function($http) {
    return {
         getUser: function() {
             return $http.get(urlBase+'/getLoggedInUser');
         }
     };
});
```

And from every controller, I can pas the accountService method and do the following:

```
var handleSuccess = function(user, status) {
     $scope.user = user;
};
accountService.getUser().success(handleSuccess);
```

This now works fine and I can get the data in each controller like that. Is this ok? Or can it get a bit nicer than that?

Comment: you need to use angular http interceptor

Comment: Where do you define **datax**. Is it a typo??

Comment: @Reena Sorry that was my mistake in the post I editted it.

Comment: @pankajparkar currently looking into that a little bit.

Comment: @JustLearning take a look at this http://beletsky.net/2013/11/simple-authentication-in-angular-dot-js-app.html

Comment: @pankajparkar Thank you, based on your post, I did the following (please see the main updated post). Now it is working fine and I don't have to repeat it. I don't know whether my approach is fine as well though.

Comment: @JustLearning should I add answer?

Comment: @pankajparkar please do if you could.

Comment: @JustLearning I've added an answer.Please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `httpInterceptor`, which can watch on your each `$http` request and response. Basically you could create a service with `request` & `response` function

**Factory**

```
angular.module('dashboardApp').factory('httpInterceptor', function httpInterceptor ($q, $window, $location) {
  return function (promise) {
      var success = function (response) {
          return response;
      };

      var error = function (response) {
          if (response.status === 401) {
              $location.url('/login');
          }

          return $q.reject(response);
      };

      return promise.then(success, error);
  };
});
```

Then do add this interceptor at configuration phase of angular life cycle that is using `app.config` (config block)

**Config**

```
angular.module('dashboardApp').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
   //your other code here like register state & configuration settings
}]);
```

Also refer [**this link**](http://$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('httpInterceptor');), which will provide you better idea how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I really appreciate it. But doing that gives me the following error:
Cannot read property 'responseInterceptors' of undefined.  While I did the following just as in the tutorial to define it: myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){

But regardless, what do you think of my new approach? Is it not considered to be good?

Comment: @JustLearning there should be `interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');`, tak a look at my update in answer

Comment: I will try to figure out how to fetch the user from the intercept method now. ;) No YOU thanks!

Comment: @JustLearning I'd loved to help you in that, let me know if you add any question on SO..Thanks :)